# PayFast Payment Integration in PHP - signature error

Tags: php, payment-gateway

Can any one help me in this PayFast payment gateway integration?
I have tried the below code, but the signature is not generating correctly I can't understand why.

```
<?php
$str = "merchant_id=10000100&merchant_key=46f0cd694581a&return_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ioss.in%2Fpayment-gateway-integration&cancel_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ioss.in&notify_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ioss.in%2Ffacebook%2Fpayfast_success.php&name_first=Bob&name_last=Smith&email_address=sbtu01%40payfast.co.za&m_payment_id=TRN123456789&amount=200.00&item_name=Widget+Model+123&item_description=Widget+Model+123";
$md5 = md5($str);

?>

<form action="https://sandbox.payfast.co.za/eng/process" method="post" name="frmPay" id="frmPay">

<!-- Receiver Details -->
<input type="hidden" name="merchant_id" value="10000100">
<input type="hidden" name="merchant_key" value="46f0cd694581a">


<input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="http://www.ioss.in/payment-gateway-integration/">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_url" value="http://www.ioss.in">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.ioss.in/facebook/payfast_success.php">

<!-- Payer Details -->
<input type="hidden" name="name_first" value="Bob">
<input type="hidden" name="name_last" value="Smith">
<input type="hidden" name="email_address" value="sbtu01@payfast.co.za"> 

<!-- Transaction Details -->
<input type="hidden" name="m_payment_id" value="TRN123456789">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="200.00">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Widget Model 123">
<input type="hidden" name="item_description" value="Widget Model 123">

<!-- Transaction Options -->
<input type="hidden" name="email_confirmation" value="">

<!-- Security -->
<input type="hidden" name="signature" value="<?php echo $md5; ?>">

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">

</form>
```

This is the code that I have tried.

The supplied variables are not according to specification:

signature : Generated signature does not match submitted signature

This is the error I am getting.

Comment: "Isn't working" as the only description of your problem isn't enough. People cannot help you like that. "Car-mechanic? My car isn't working. Please help. What should I do?"

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself." I am therefore flagging this to be closed..

Comment: You don't have to be harsh on him, almost all the requirement is correct, the only issue is the Passphrase, always add the passphrase as the last parameter is your signature... unfortunately documentation is not very clear on it.

Answer (score 4):

// Create GET string from your array (Sample below from array $params)

```
$pfOutput ='';
foreach( $params as $key => $val )
{
    if(!empty($val))
    {
        $pfOutput .= $key .'='. urlencode( trim( $val ) ) .'&';
    }
}
// Remove last ampersand

$getString = substr( $pfOutput, 0, -1 );
if( isset( $passPhrase ) && $paymode!='sandbox' )
{
    $getString .= '&passphrase='.$passPhrase;
}

$pfSignature = md5( $getString );
$params['signature'] = $pfSignature;
```

// POST

```
    $url = "https://sandbox.payfast.co.za/eng/process/?" . $getString;
    redirect($url);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to calculate the signature *after* you've processed the inputs, as it's based on them.

Changing any value would alter the signature.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in [official documentation](https://www.payfast.co.za/documentation/confirm-page/)

> **Why am I getting a signature mismatch error?**
>
> This is most likely caused if you generated the MD5 hashed string with the variables in the wrong order, they need to be in the order as they appear in the tables above. Another reason could be that you have not URLencoded the variable values and trimmed all white spaces off the ends using PHP’s `trim()` function, or the resultant `URLencoding` is in `lower case` (eg. `http%3a%2f%2f`) instead of the required `upper case` (eg. `http%3A%2F%2F`).

Reason for following error(The supplied variables are not according to specification:) is you dont have to submit blank values as mentioned in official documentation (How to generate signature)

> A security signature of the transmitted data taking the form of an MD5 hash of the submitted variables. The string from which the hash is created, is the concatenation of the name value pairs of all the **non-blank variables** with ‘&’ used as a separator eg. “`name_first=John&name_last=Doe&email_address=…`” where pairs are listed in the order in which they appear on this page. This hash will be regenerated by the PayFast engine and the values compared to ensure the integrity of the data transfer.

You are sending `<input type="hidden" name="email_confirmation" value="">`blank values that is causing issue. Simply remove this field and you will have no issue.(PayFast will automatically confirm email as stated in documentation)

Comment: I'd just like to add to your answer, that when it is said "they need to be in the order as they appear in the tables above", they REALLY mean, the URL MUST be built with the query params in the EXACT order as they are listed here: https://developers.payfast.co.za/docs#step_1_form_fields. I.e. first merchant_id, then merchant_key etc.

Answer (score 2):

you can check your signature in signature generator tool of payfast. 
link : https://sandbox.payfast.co.za/

after open this link click on "open tool" button of "POST CHECK" section.

then it will open dialog box for generate signature.
copy full request url and past in textbox after that hit "Generate Signature" button.

by using this you will get all errors if have in URL, also check both signature.

Answer (score 0):

Always add your passphrase as the last parameter is of your signature... unfortunately documentation is not very clear on it.

[image: here is a gen from the sandbox]

This is not an MD5 Convertor ;) to get the same signature, just add &passphrase=yourpassphrase at the end of your string. then your convert in MD5

[image]

Answer (score -2):

your email_confirmation input value is empty and you are not including it at all in the md5 calculation.

Since you have no value rather remove the input.  Otherwise give it a value and include it in your md5 calculation.